# Trying to use oninput event with python flask

Tags: python, html, flask, oninput

I'm trying to make a program using html and python flask. In this program I have a list of data and a search field where the user can search thru their data. I would like that as soon as the user starts typing, I can take what he has typed and save it to a variable.
The problem is happening in the oninput, it seems that it is not working correctly.
I don't get eny erros, it simply doesn't do the python code.

This is my html code:

```
<form class="d-flex" role="search">
    <input oninput="{{ url_for( 'search') }}" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
</form>
```

And this is my python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

@app.route('/search', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def search():
    # the program is never getting to this part
    users_input = request.form['search']
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Is there any way I can make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) is not suitable for passing a URL in order to send the data automatically. This is a JavaScript event for which a function must be registered as a handler in order to react to the event. The work of sending the data thus remains with the developer.

First, however, you should decide whether your data requires a transfer using a GET or POST request.

With a GET request, the form data is sent after a '?', separated by '&' within the URL. These can be extracted on the server side using `request.args`. This is the usual procedure for a search query.

However, if you use a POST request, the form data is sent within the request body and can be queried via `request.form`. The request data is better protected from the eyes of third parties and is not limited in size.

Below is a simple example that you can adapt to your needs. The form's data is sent via AJAX through the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and the server's response is inserted into the page.

###### Python Flask

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Define the required request-methods here.
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET']) 
def search():
    # Use request.args.get('search', '') for a GET request
    # or request.form.get('search', '') for a POST request.
    user_input = request.args.get('search', '')
    return render_template('results.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (./templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
        <input type="search" name="search" oninput="handleInput(event)" />
    </form>

    <div id="results"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleInput(event) {
            const submitEvent = new SubmitEvent('submit', { submitter: event.target });
            event.target.form.dispatchEvent(submitEvent);
        }
        function handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const url = {{ url_for('search') | tojson }};

            /* If you use a GET request. */
            const formData = new FormData(event.target);
            const params = Array.from(formData.keys(), key => {
                return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(formData.get(key))}`;
            }).join('&');
            
            fetch(`${url}?${params}`)
                .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.text())
                .then(text => {
                    const elem = document.getElementById('results');
                    elem && (elem.innerHTML = text);
                });

            /* If you use a POST request. */
            // fetch(url, {
            //  method: 'POST', 
            //  body: new FormData(event.target)
            // })
            //  .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.text())
            //  .then(text => {
            //      const elem = document.getElementById('results');
            //      elem && (elem.innerHTML = text);
            //  });
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

###### HTML (./templates/results.html)

```
<p>Your results for "{{user_input}}" here!</p>
```